# Can we scale a div by the window's width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Let's say I can't manipulate div's content so I should change div's shape and shrink it by `transform: scale(1.4)` for examole

To get a better idea about the question check out [This Website](https://www.varzesh3.com/) and try to resize the window via browser dev tools.

Notice how the whole app just changes its shape (with no overflow)
rather than moving element in order to make the site responsive!

How can we achieve that via css?

I tried `vw`&`vh` but that just changes the width/height according to screen size.
Also I tried to implement that with `transform: scale(1.5)` but that should be an specific number I wonder if we could use a number inside `scale(HERE)` that kinda works like `vw`

**I didn't provide a executable example since that's just a simple div :)**

Here is an example

[image]

Comment: The website you putted in example is not responsive in my case (I'm using safari ....)

Comment: @A.Vinuela I believe that is what the question is about

Comment: @A.Vinuela I just used it with Safari and got the same result. Try to use it with Chrome if possible. Although it's not responsive it just scales the elements according to screen size

Comment: I don't get why using vw is not a valid option ? It does exactly what you're asking for

Comment: @Xanthous With `vw` we can say that div's width is equal to for example 12 percent of view port width, hence VW. So the content size inside that div will not change accordingly. I hope you "get" that.

Comment: You'll have to use Javascript to do that ... It's gonna be difficult with css

Answer (score 0):

CSS flexbox might be what you are looking for. You can add `display:flex` and `flex-wrap:wrap` to the parent div to achieve the required effect.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Comment: Where can I see the gif? I do not see it in the question